# Some PDF fails to open with error "internet explorer cannot display the webpage" from a document library

Tags: document-library, document, pdf, internet-explorer

We recently upgraded our browser Internet Explorer(Standard browser for our organization) from IE 8 to IE 9 and since then just one user(not all) having issue opening few PDF documents.
In a same document library some PDF opens OK within the browser but for few documents, it throws an error "internet explorer cannot display the webpage".
It just fails to locate those some the PDF documents. When open in explorer view PDF documents opens OK, no drama.

We tried to fix and upgrade adobe acrobat with no luck. 
When we roll back to IE 8 it fixes the issue. Also only one user is having this issue and we don't want to roll back to IE 8.

Our setup is following.
SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.
IE 9

It is very frustrating as some PDF works and some not. Running out of troubleshooting ideas. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am just asking for a bit more information to see where the problem might be. If it is a client or server issue. My guess is that it is a client issue. You said that the problem only appeared for one user? Have you tried to ask that user to log on another machine to see if the problem still occurs ? (And another user on his (the problem) machine to see if this occurs?) Is it always the same PDF files that cant be opened?

Comment: It is a client issue. A couple of more users (out of hundreds) reported same issue. When they login to another machines all good. Yes same pdf files all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the below path and disable the option:

Adobe Reader -> Edit -> Internet -> Open in browser (Uncheck the option)

Answer (score 0):

Could this help?

http://msdnrss.thecoderblogs.com/2011/12/internet-explorer-fails-to-open-pdf-file/

If not, collect ProcMon and Network Trace and try to spot the difference.